# Why is R Studio telling me that } is unexpected in my For loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a simple loop to transform each column of a data frame - which were read into R as factors - to numeric form. My code seems to work fine when transforming an individual column into a percentage, but I can't figure out how to write the for loop.

```
# Transform data into numeric form
For i in 5:ncol(df){
    vector.i <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df[,i])) / 100
    next
    }
```

As you can see, I only want to transform the columns from column 5 on. I am fine with creating the results as individual vectors.

> Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: `For` is. not camelcase `for(i in 5:ncol(df))` and `vector.i` may be `assign(paste0("vector.", i), as.numeric(sub("%", "", df[,i])) / 100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating akrun's comment into an answer, R's for-loops and vector names do not work like that, but you could try

```
for (i in 5:ncol(df)){ 
    assign(paste0("vector.", i), as.numeric(sub("%", "", df[, i])) / 100)
    }
```

Comment: So is assigning things with the <- operator always a no-no in an R for-loop?

Comment: No they aren't saying that. But if you assign to vector.i it will assign literally to "vector.i". It's not going to transform that to vector.1 and vector.2 etc...